# Removing NaN from dictionary inside dictionary (Dict changes size during runtime error)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

using to_dict() I come up with the following dictionary. I need to drop all nan values. This approach doesn't work because it changes size during iteration. Is there another way to accomplish this?

```
{'k': {'a': nan, 'b': 1.0, 'c': 1.0},
 'u': {'a': 1.0, 'b': nan, 'c': 1.0},
 'y': {'a': nan, 'b': 1.0, 'c': nan}}
In [196]:

for listing, rate in master_dict.items():
for key in rate:
    if pd.isnull(master_dict[listing][key]) == True:
        del master_dict[listing][key]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-200-8859eb717bb9> in <module>()
      1 for listing, rate in master_dict.items():
----> 2     for key in rate:
      3         if pd.isnull(master_dict[listing][key]) == True:
      4             del master_dict[listing][key]
      5 

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use double `dict comprehension` with filtering with [`pandas.notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) or [`pandas.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html):

```
y = {k1:{k:v for k,v in v1.items() if pd.notnull(v)} for k1, v1 in d.items()}
print (y)
{'k': {'c': 1.0, 'b': 1.0}, 'u': {'c': 1.0, 'a': 1.0}, 'y': {'b': 1.0}}
```

Similar solution:

```
y = {k1:{k:v for k,v in v1.items() if not pd.isnull(v)} for k1, v1 in d.items()}
print (y)
{'k': {'c': 1.0, 'b': 1.0}, 'u': {'c': 1.0, 'a': 1.0}, 'y': {'b': 1.0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

An incremental fix on your code would be:

```
for key in list(rate.keys()):  # make a copy and Python won't complain
```

A more pythonic solution would be to use dict compenhension to remove items:

```
for listing, rate in master_dict.items():
    master_dict[listing] = {k: v for k, v in rate.items() if pd.notnull(v)}
```

Comment: This comment helped me understand @jezrael 's inline version. ty.

Comment: @Artem Yevtushenko i won't prefer an inline double-comprehension in Python.  It is not very readable to me.  However I would be glad to do it that way in Perl since readability is the last thing to worry there :)